# Typing TestCafe userVariables configuration with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've been trying to work with the `.testcaferc.js` configuration file in my project to consolidate some configuration that has been spread out until now.

Regarding the userVariables configuration, I'm unsure of how to type this so that the object is not `unknown`.  I could just import the variables from `.testcaferc.js` directly whenever I need to use a `userVariable`, but that is not the example that is shown in the [docs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file?search#uservariables).

Does anyone know the preferred way to go about this? Should I use a declaration file here? I really like the idea of this global configuration file and would love to get it to work, but so far it's been a bit difficult with Typescript it seems especially when working with global hooks.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to generate these types during tests' compilation. However, you can define your own interface with all desired types.

*project\test\user-variables\index.ts:*

```
import { userVariables } from 'testcafe'

export interface TypedUserVariables {
   [key: string]: unknown;

   result?: string
}

export const typedUserVariables = userVariables as TypedUserVariables;
```

*project\test\test.ts:*

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { typedUserVariables } from './user-variables';

test('Test', async t => {
   const typedStringVariable = typedUserVariables.result; //Will be a string here
})
```

Please let me know if this approach is suitable for you.

Regards,
Artemy

Comment: Hey Artemy, thank you for this approach!

I do wish there was a way to not have to create another export especially when the userVariables are mostly constants.  I'll most likely go with your approach of typing and re-exporting the userVariables though, thanks!